pinescript で time frame を取得し、if 5m, then plot 200SMA, if 15m then plot 20SMA. したいですが、[Cannot use 'plot' in local scope] のエラーになる
pinescriptについて教えて下さい。
やりたいことは以下です：
time frame を取得し、
if 5m, then plot 200SMA, 
if 15m, then plot 20SMA.

実装したら、[Cannot use 'plot' in local scope] とエラーになります。
調べた結果、条件付きプロットを作成するには、代わりに関数の最初の引数をプロットされた値に設定する必要があるようです。うまくできませんでした。
ご教示頂けると嬉しいです。
if (current_timeframe == "5")
    plot(my, sma_5m_20, color=color.blue, title="SMA20 (5m)")
    plot(my, sma_5m_200, color=color.red, title="SMA200 (5m)")
    plot(my, sma_5m_240, color=color.green, title="SMA240 (5m)")

else if (current_timeframe == "15")
    plot(shiwu, sma_15m_20, color=color.blue, title="SMA20 (15m)")
    plot(shiwu, sma_15m_80, color=color.red, title="SMA80 (15m)")
    plot(shiwu, sma_15m_200, color=color.green, title="SMA200 (15m)")


こんな記事が参考になるかも。How to put plot statement inside if statement, TradingView if statements cannot execute functions? ('Cannot use in local scope' error)

例えばこれらの記事は色だけを変えるためのものですが、他のパラメータについても同様にif文で判定して代入する変数を作れば良いのでは？ 三項演算子（?:）, Pine Script（Pineスクリプト）の三項条件演算子「?:」の使い方（v5はiff関数廃止）

自力で解決しました。条件付き文をplot関数の引数にする。
plot((current_timeframe == "5") ? sma_5m_20 : na,  color=color.silver, title="SMA20 (5m)", linewidth = 1)

詳細な解決策の提示と情報共有のためにコメントではなく自身で回答してみてください。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。自分の質問に回答できますか？
